# Mean of target variable differs by one percent for independent variable, yet it has a coefficient of 0.43 and is highly significant in logistic reg

Tags: regression, logistic, nonlinear-regression, statsmodels

I have a dataset that contains information on what an individual likes! The question is posed do you get energy from ..... (my X). These X variables are categories. One of these categories is whether someone gets energy from and enjoys playing `sport`. It is true if someone answered yes and false if they answered no.

The target variable is whether someone passed an undergraduate course. This is a binary variable 1 indicating a pass and 0 indicating a fail.

504 students indicated they enjoyed and gained energy from playing sports. `66.4%` of these students passed the course. 244 students indicated they did enjoy playing sports or gained energy from it. `65.9%` of these students passed the course. This seems like a very small difference and given that the dataset is not that large I would not expect this to be significant. Yet, when I perform a logistic regression on this dataset (including the other categories such as social activities, events, entertainment) it shows that sport is highly significant (`z-value` of 3) and has a coefficeint of `0.43`. If I correct interpret this coefficient value it would mean that someone that enjoys sports has a 53% higher chance of passing the course. This value does not pass my sanity check when comparing it with the mean and the sample size of both groups. What is going on here? What am I missing?

I am using the `statsmodels` api with the `Logit` model.

Below is the model output generated by the `summary` method.

https://gyazo.com/0616c6eeb576d149274efdf14ad54a2a

I added gender as a control variable.

Comment: AFAICS, you don’t have a constant in the model. That makes the coefficients more difficult to interpret because they include a level effect and not just a marginal effect.

Answer (score 0):

If you only sports and the target, does the same thing happen? If not, then either (a) sports alone does not have that predictive power, or (b) some other variable confounds to occlude the effect of sports.

Then start from your full model and remove variables until the effect goes away. Find the smallest set of variables that recreate that effect.

Explore those variables visually together. Why does sports modify the effect of the other? Maybe ask follow-up questions of the subjects.

Without access to your data or more details on how you decided which variables to include in the model, we can't explain what has happened.